# identifier mod is undefined | filename extension .c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{

 float x,y,z;

 printf("Enter the value of x,y:");
 scanf("%f%f",&x,&y);

 z= 2.5*log(x)+cos(32)+ mod(x*x-y*y)+ sqrt(2*x*y);

 printf(" The value of the expression is %f",z);


}
```

Comment: You really need to format your code before posting. Also, there is no actual question. What are you trying to achieve? The modulus function in C is `%`.

Comment: It is unclear what is the question, please provide more details about what seems to be the problem

Comment: Where's the `mod()` function defined? Did you mean to use `modf()`? Did you link with the math library with `-lm`?

Comment: What is `mod`? There is no standard function called `mod`, and the most likely candidate, `fmod`, takes two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

By the equation you are solving, I feel that you want to find the absolute value of `x*x - y*y`. Something like `|x|`.

In that case, you should use `fabs(x*x -y*y)`. It returns double.